# I passed a state via Link, but i can't display them in my component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In a list component I have passed data via `Link`, like so

```
playListState.map((list) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Link
        to={`/playlists/${list.id}`}
        state={{ from: list }}
        key={list.id}
      >
        <p>{list.title}</p>
      </Link>
```

Then in the component that I want to use the props from the data that I passed.
I try to get them via `useLocation` like so,

```
const location = useLocation();
const { title, songs,  } = location.state as PlayList; 
console.log(location.state, "location");
```

`PlayList` are the props of the data I am passing.
In the log I see the state that I am passing but
when I log title it's undefined. I have looked online and
tried to implement a few things, but without success. So how can I get the data that a passed and display it in my component?

Comment: The data is passed in route state is passed on `state.from`, so it should be accessed from `state.from` in the receiving component. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you saying but when i do this ```  const { from } = location.state 
  console.log(from.title, "location"); ``` from is giving me the following error TS2339: Property 'from' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Comment: Try typing the `state` object, i.e. `const { from } = location.state as /* type declaration with from */`. It should be something like `interface RouteState { from: PlayList; }` or similar, and then `const { from } = location.state as RouteState`.